# difference between slurm sbatch -n and -c

Tags: mpi, openmp, shared-memory, distributed-computing, slurm

The cluster that I work with recently switched from SGE to SLURM. I was wondering what the difference between `sbatch` options `--ntasks` and `--cpus-per-task`?

`--ntasks` seemed appropriate for some MPI jobs that I ran but did not seem appropriate for some OpenMP jobs that I ran.

For the OpenMP jobs in my SLURM script, I specified:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=20
```

All the nodes in the partition are 20core machines, so only 1 job should run per machine.  However, multiple jobs were running simultaneously on each node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tasks in SLURM are basically processes / mpi ranks - it seems you just want a single task. A task can be multithreaded. The of cpus per taks is set via `-c, --cpus-per-task`. If you use hyperthreading it becomes a little bit more complicated, as explains in `man srun`.